# How to show LA*B* value of a specific pixel in image?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Previously there was code 'pixval on' to show value of rgb in every pixel of image.
Now already obsolete.
I wonder how to do the same thing for LAB converted image.

Answer (score 1):

First, create a figure with the image

```
function so1
   global im;
   im = imread('peppers.png');
   figure;imshow(im);    
 end
```

Then, create a new Data cursor, choose "Select text update func"
[image]

and select the following callback file:

```
function output_txt = NewCallback(obj,event_obj)
% Display the position of the data cursor
% obj          Currently not used (empty)
% event_obj    Handle to event object
% output_txt   Data cursor text string (string or cell array of strings).
global im;
pos = get(event_obj,'Position');
val = squeeze(im(pos(2),pos(1),:))';
srgb2lab = makecform('srgb2lab');
labVal = applycform(val,srgb2lab);
output_txt = sprintf('LAB = [%d,%d,%d]',labVal(1),labVal(2),labVal(3));
```

The only drawback here is the ugly use of global, which probably can be removed, but it is not the issue.